# nhibernate how to I represent a collection of or predicates

Tags: linq, nhibernate

In SQL I can write a statement like this:
`SELECT * FROM Clients  Where 
(clientId = 1 and lastname = 'smith' or partnerlastname='jones') 
OR (clientId = 2 and lastname = 'brown' or partnerlastname='campbell')

OR (clientId = 3 and lastname = 'higgins' or partnerlastname='cholmondely')`

I'm trying to do something similar in nhhibernate using linq passing through an enumerable of predicates for each of the ORs.

I can seem to wrangle c# enough to make it work though... Is is possible? How would I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a predicate builder class like this:

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

```
  public static class PredicateBuilder
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a predicate that evaluates to true.
        /// </summary>
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return param => true; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a predicate that evaluates to false.
        /// </summary>
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return param => false; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a predicate expression from the specified lamda expression.
        /// </summary>
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Create<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) { return predicate; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Combines the first predicate with the second using the logical "and".
        /// </summary>
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
        {
            return first.Compose(second, Expression.AndAlso);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Combines the first predicate with the second using the logical "not".
        /// </summary>
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Not<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Not(expr.Body), expr.Parameters);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Combines the first predicate with the second using the logical "or".
        /// </summary>
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
        {
            return first.Compose(second, Expression.OrElse);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Combines the first expression with the second using the specified merge function.
        /// </summary>
        static Expression<T> Compose<T>(this Expression<T> first, Expression<T> second, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> merge)
        {
            // build parameter map (from parameters of second to parameters of first)
            var map = first.Parameters
                .Select((f, i) => new { f, s = second.Parameters[i] })
                .ToDictionary(p => p.s, p => p.f);

            // replace parameters in the second lambda expression with parameters from the first
            var secondBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(map, second.Body);

            // apply composition of lambda expression bodies to parameters from the first expression
            return Expression.Lambda<T>(merge(first.Body, secondBody), first.Parameters);
        }

        class ParameterRebinder : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map;

            ParameterRebinder(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map)
            {
                this.map = map ?? new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>();
            }

            public static Expression ReplaceParameters(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map, Expression exp)
            {
                return new ParameterRebinder(map).Visit(exp);
            }

            protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression p)
            {
                ParameterExpression replacement;

                if (map.TryGetValue(p, out replacement))
                {
                    p = replacement;
                }

                return base.VisitParameter(p);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have had an issue using this predicate builder, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156027/how-to-generate-static-true-false-criteria-instead-of-parameterized-true-false-c